# Module route with subdirectory handling

Tags: magento-1.9, router

I'm trying to create a module with a route that handles filter. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/routename/color/blue/size/small
```

How can I setup the route so that it handles all child directories/paths (and throws 404s when not found)?

Comment: You can do this using other concept, pass the value either using Post or Get into magento.

Comment: I would like sharable, indexable URLs.